# bootstrap dropdown menu overlap wrapping div

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

What is the proper way to allow a bootstrap button dropdown to overlap the containing div?  The containing div has overflow-y:scroll.  The current problem is when  containing dropdown contents is displayed the contents stay within the scrollable div.

Tried using absolute positioning of dropdown, changing position css to fixed does allow the overlap.  Is that the proper way?

Here is jsfiddle demonstrating:
http://jsfiddle.net/weaver_je/pA6cx/1/

The first button (.btn1) with position: fixed is closest to desired output.

```
<div style="width:120px; height:150px; overflow-y:scroll;">
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn dropdown-toggle btn1" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

    <br/><br/>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn dropdown-toggle btn2" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>

$(".btn1").click(function (e) {         
    $(".dropdown-menu").css({
        position:"fixed",
        display: "block",
        left: e.pageX,
       top: e.pageY
    });

    return false;
});

$(".btn2").click(function (e) {           
    $(".dropdown-menu").css({
        position:"absolute",
        display: "block",
        left: e.pageX,
        top: e.pageY
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem here too. It seems that there is no good solution for this. The only one I can think is the make the `dropdown-menu` use `position:fixed` and set its top/left with JS. Of course this has an issue too when you scroll, so I guess we will need more JS code...? Bind onto every scroller up the DOM and wait for scroll events? :o    It is funny that people make apps on the web without a good way to make menus that work everywhere... If engineers built things like that, humanity would have been burned into ashes by now...

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this just by CSS:

**Bootply** : http://jsfiddle.net/pA6cx/2/

**CSS** :

```
body > div > div.dropdown.open {
position: absolute;
}
```

*Just available for first button, I didn't edit the second...*

**After comment** :
Jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/fw522/2/

```
body > div > div.dropdown.open:hover{
position: absolute;
}
```

*Set to absolute position only when mouse is over*

Comment: Thanks, this helps.  The dropdown container overlaps the container div with that css.  There is one issue that I still need to solve.  When the dropdown is open and you scroll down in container, the dropdown remains open and in fixed position instead of scrolling with rest of content in div.  Any tips for that?  http://jsfiddle.net/fw522/

Comment: Also, notice that if you scroll first then open the dropdown it's in the wrong place.

Comment: The hover causes some strange behavior.  Biggest issue is if you scroll down at all and then click on the button it doesn't work.  Also, would like to find a way that would avoid losing the overlap when mouse moves outside of the dropdown container.

Answer (score 3):

I solved similar problem by moving the `dropdown-toggle` button outside the `dropdown` div, adding the `data-target` attribute to the button pointing to that div, and making the div's position absolute.

Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pA6cx/58/

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn dropdown-toggle btn1" type="button" data-target="#dropdown1" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
  Dropdown
  <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<div class="dropdown" id="dropdown1">
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use fixed positioning on the drop-down and set its position with JavaScript:

```
var dropdown = $element.find('.dropdown-menu');
var button = $element.find('.btn.dropdown-toggle');
function positionDropDown() {
    dropdown.css('top', button.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop() + button.outerHeight() + "px");
    dropdown.css('left', button.offset().left + "px");
}
button.click(positionDropDown);
dropdown.css('position', 'fixed');
```

One problem with this is when the user opens the drop-down and then scrolls the container. In that case, the dropdown will not follow the button.

To fix that, I guess one would have to bind to the `scroll` event of every container he finds up the DOM and update the dropdown position in the handler. An oversimplified example is this where we handle the window scroll only:

```
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
    positionDropDown();
});
```

Imagine doing that for every parent container of the dropdown in the DOM and you have the hack to make HTML and CSS work as it should in the first place...